# How to run custom sql commands to database programatically

Tags: 8, database

I'm using MariaDB as database backend and I would like to use built in "Sequences" to get an integer number generator. I need to dinamically create sequences and get their values. Following [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequences/) documentation I know the right sql commands to do it and I have tested it on MariaDB, but I haven't found a way to run this commands from Drupal 8 database connection object. I can only do selects, updates, inserts or deletes. How could I run this custom sql? I need it because I have to create custom sequences on submit some form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I haven't found a way to run this commands from Drupal 8 database connection object. I can only do selects, updates, inserts or deletes

That's not true, you can also run arbitrary queries, e.g.:

```
\Drupal::database()->query('TRUNCATE TABLE foo');
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I've tried with "CREATE SEQUENCE..." but I always got an error and I supposed I didn't work. I don't know what I did to get this error. I'm sorry. You are right. It works good.

Answer (score -1):

You can run your SQL query in your Drupal Project. Read this  [Static Queries](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/static-queries) Article. you will get detailed explaination of syntax and examples.